# Add tooltip to select element in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Anyone know how to add a Bootstrap 3 tooltip to a select element?

Having no problems with inputs or textareas.

```
<select data-toggle='tooltip' data-trigger='focus' data-placement='top' title='The number of tags to create.'>
```

Tried changing data-trigger to something else like 'hover' but no luck! The JS event handler we're using is as follows:

```
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").each(function (index, el) {
    $(el).tooltip({
        placement: $(this).data("placement") || 'top'
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create the tooltips like this..

```
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip({
    placement: $(this).data("placement") || 'top'
});
```

Working Demo: http://bootply.com/89593